# docker container nginx

Tags: nginx, docker, ftp, winscp

Есть несколько сайтов на пхп которые работают внутри контейнера nginx. Возможно ли получить удаленный доступ к файлам сайтов по средствам ftp\winscp?

p.s.
Начинаю только осваивать docker.

Comment: попробуйте так https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=22893

Comment: этот вариант не работает